# "getFile" method in Telegram Bot API

Tags: android, telegram, telegram-bot

In Telegram Bot API there's a method "getFile" https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile. I have a bot for testing and have Telegram install on Android. How do I test this method, should I send a file to my bot? If so, then how exactly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If someone has sent your bot a file (photo, video, document, audio, etc), `getFile` returns information which allows your bot to download the file. To test this method, do the following:

1. Use the Android Telegram app to send your bot a photo.
2. Open a browser, enter in the address bar `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getUpdates`

   You should see several `file_id`s in the response. These are thumbnails of the photo.
3. Pick a `file_id` of your choice. Enter in the browser's address bar `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getFile?file_id=<file_id>`

   Look for `file_path` in the response. It should look something like `photo\/file_22.jpg`. The backslash is only to escape the forward slash, so the `file_path` is actually `photo/file_22.jpg`
4. Enter in the address bar `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>`

   You should see the corresponding thumbnail of the photo.

To download the file programmatically, you may follow the exact same steps as above, or you may use a library such as **[telepot](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot)** (Python), which provides a method to download files conveniently, without going through all the above steps.

Comment: Downloading the image I get a bad quality image instead of the original. Is there a way to get the original image (width/height)? Thanks.

Comment: Aren't there many sizes to choose from? Just pick the size you want.

Comment: How can I do that? Using : https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path> I can see the image but smaller and bad quality than the original. If i download the image then scale it I get a very bad quality image

Comment: Im using php how can i migrate? Easy? Convert my bot code from php to python? Need change my linux server?

Comment: @Mattia telegram client resize them before upload to telegram cdn servers. Before that converts, your users must select orginal upload method instead of optimize method

Comment: @Mattia for quality, it's because you are downloading the thumbnail. in python you need to use `update.message.photo[-1]['file_id']` instead of `update.message.photo[0]['file_id']` to download the original image. technically the first one is thumbnail the last one is original image in array